# Use variable as argument in slice

Tags: javascript

I am trying to put in **slice()** some arguments from outside.

```
var string = "How are you doing today?";


var start = '0,7';
var result = string.slice(start);


alert(result);
```

I am expecting to see in alert "How are" but i am getting full string.

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sb7s432f/)**

Comment: You can't do it that way -- slice is attempting to convert your string to a single int.  You will have to parse the string to the two values, and pass those as the parameters to `slice`.

Comment: @one2gov: have you the read the documentation for slice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to split up the `start` string into two integers:

```
var split = start.split(',');
var begin = parseInt(split[0], 10);
var end = parseInt(split[1], 10);
var result = string.slice(begin, end);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't provide two comma separated arguments as a string. What you could do is split the string on a `,` by using `start.split(',')` and then pass each of the arguments separately, such as

```
var foo = start.split(',');
string.slice(+foo[0], +foo[1]);
```

The unary `+` here simply stands for a conversion to a `Number`. You could also use the `parseInt` function

```
var foo = start.split(',');
string.slice(parseInt(foo[0], 10), parseInt(foo[1], 10));
```

The `10` in `parseInt` means to convert the value to base 10

Answer (score 0):

The method `slice()` is either a one parameter or two parameter function whose syntax is defined here:

```
arrayObj.slice(start, [end]);
```

In the first result, you declare two parameters, so the result is as you expect.

```
var result1 = string.slice(0,7);
```

In the second result, the two 'parameters' are actually stored in one variable, so you're really calling the one-parameter version of the function.

```
var result2 = string.slice(start);
```

I'm not quite sure if the `slice()` method fails (probably does) or there's some weird way the function treats the non-sense parameter (could also be the case), but the result is the same: `result2` is just simply the value of the original String.

*Solution:*

Separate the variables to call the two-parameter version of the overloaded function.

Comment: Thank you for explanation of this process.

Comment: Not a problem! I hope this helped you!

Comment: I am sorry. How do you thing should i choose 1 answer? If there is a three helpful answers. 1 with theoretical explanation and 2 different working code.

Comment: I would choose the answer that was most helpful to you and that you think would be most beneficial to the community. Check out [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19448/etiquette-for-selecting-answers).

Comment: Thank you for answer and link. I think my choice would be better for the community. I don't know yet what answer i will use in the end.

Answer (score -1):

```
var start = 0;
var end = 7;

var result = string.slice(start, end);
```

Comment: Your method is working. But in reality this two numbers will be always diffetent, and i will get them from _.range() function.

Comment: So it always comes in as a comma-delimited string?

Comment: `_.range(0, 7)` produces `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`.  I don't see where `'0,7'` is coming from.  `_.range('0,7')` produces an error "invalid array length".

Comment: something like this, to get two numbers
`var seven = 7;`
`var start = _.range(0, seven, seven-1);`

Comment: In your code there, `start` will be `[0, 6]` not `'0,7'`.  Is `seven` passed into your function?

Comment: nwm it's just an example

Comment: Perhaps, but it's not illustrative and therefore not helpful.

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand what is not illustrative. I just made an example of how to get 2 symbols from `._range()` function. Anyway this function give us something, that cannnot be `.split()`
Therefore i used `toString()` to work with `._range()` output.

Comment: Because the value in your question is `'0,7'` but the value given by `range()` is `[0, 6]`.  The code doesn't illustrate the same thing.  If you want to use `range()`'s output, try `start[0]` and `start[1]`.